# How to Set the Category When Posting to WordPress from Python Using Wordpresslib

Tags: php, python, wordpress, module

There's not much in the documentation of this old Wordpresslib module on how to post to a specific category. Looking through the code of the module itself shows lots of category related classes in it.
('World' is a category already set on the WP site I'm posting to.)
I've tried these below but everytime the category of the post on WP is "Uncategorized"...

```
post.setPostCategories = ["World"]
post.categories = ["World"]
post.WordPressCategory = ["World"]
```

Not sure if this involves keys or something or if I'll have to import another module to set the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The categories are already set on your WP site as numbers.
Post to them like this when using the Wordpresslib module...

```
post.categories = ["4"]
```